# IDL cumulative histogram

Tags: histogram, idl-programming-language

I have an array of data, and I want to make a cumulative histogram with it in IDL. Is there an input that I can use on a HISTOGRAM, PLOTHIST, PHIST, or HISTO command that will do this for me? If there is, how do I use it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try the `CUMULATIVE` keyword to `TOTAL`:

```
IDL> x = randomu(seed, 1000) * 100.
IDL> h = histogram(x, binsize=10)  
IDL> ch = total(h, /cumulative, /preserve_type)        
IDL> plot, ch, psym=10
```